# Hauptmodul for $\Gamma_1(3)$

Tags: reference-request, modular-forms

I'm looking for a nice formula for a Hauptmodul for $\Gamma_1(3)$.

This is certainly very classical.A reference would be great.

Answer (score 1):

The reference I found is the paper [Modular Subgroups, Forms, Curves
and Surfaces](http://mysite.science.uottawa.ca/asebbar/publi/mfcs.pdf) by Abdellah Sebbar. Table $3$ gives the Hauptmodul for $\Gamma(3)$, namely the modular form 
$$
\Big( \frac{\eta (\tau /3)}{\eta(3\tau)}\Big),
$$
with the Dedekind eta funtion $\eta(z)$. The Hauptmodul for $\Gamma_1(3)$ is then the third power of the one of $\Gamma(3)$, if I understood this correctly.